# Will adding another embedded document into my MongoDB user model affect the older data without those embedded documents?

Tags: mongodb

In the project I've been working on, I've added a new field - an embedded document.  Will this addition affect data prior to the change?  From what I've read this shouldn't affect prior data, and this is actually one of the benefits of using MongoDB.  Its just the previous data won't have that field.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it won't affect your previous documents - each document in your collection can have it's own unique fields if you want. It is up to you to handle this at application level.